# How to show iOS GameCenter 'dashboard' within a game?

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, game-center, gamekit, openfeint

**Situation:**
I'm using both OpenFeint/Game Center in a cocos2d game. OpenFeint has a 'dashboard' that you can present within the game, but I could not find an equivalent for Game Center.

**Question:**
I want to know how to present a Game Center 'dashboard' or home-type screen from within my game. I do not want to exit out of the game.

**Other Info:**
GameKit provides a couple of useful viewcontrollers *(GKAchievementViewController / GKLeaderboardViewController)* for showing specific leaderboards or achievements within a game, but I could not immediately find a view controller for a more generic dashboard or home-type screen.

Comment: I've never seen a GameCenter dashboard within a game- only the two screens you mentioned. I'd like to see what you come up with- good question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GameCenter has no "dashboard" view. You'd have to design your own if you wanted to combine both leaderboards, achievements or other information in a single view. Check the [Game Center documentation about customizing the Game Center views](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/GameKit_Guide/Achievements/Achievements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008304-CH7-SW10).